# Jquery - Copy text from nearest element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the code below

```
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <p>Space filler text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    <div class="copied-text">
       Space for text A
    </div>
  </header>

  <section>
    <h6>
      <a>Text A</a>
    </h6>
  </section>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <p>Space filler text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    <div class="copied-text">
       Space for text B
    </div>
  </header>

  <section>
    <h6>
      <a>Text B</a>
    </h6>
  </section>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is copy the text in the a tag to the div.copied-text element, however the I only want to copy the text unique to that specific container.

I have tried the code below but this copies both sets of text to both divs

```
$('div.copied-text').html($('h6 a').text());
```

I have also tried the code below but this does not seem to work.
    $('div.copied-text').html($(this).parent().siblings().children('h6').children('a').text());

I have set it up in jsFiddle if it helps
https://jsfiddle.net/jy5fghd8/3/
This is a working example, however in my project I have many div.container elements on one page so need the solution to adapt to each container.

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.container` as your parent:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.find(".copied-text").html($this.find("h6 a").text());
  });
});
```

The simpler or alternative version without using `.each` will be:

```
$(function () {
  $(".copied-text").html(function () {
    return $(this).closest(".container").find("h6 a").text();
  });
});
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.find(".copied-text").html($this.find("h6 a").text());
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
header {
  background-color: red;
}
section {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.copied-text {
  background-color: cyan;
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <p>Space filler text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    <div class="copied-text">
      Space for text A
    </div>
  </header>

  <section>
    <h6>
      <a>Text A</a>
    </h6>
  </section>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <p>Space filler text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    <div class="copied-text">
      Space for text B
    </div>
  </header>

  <section>
    <h6>
      <a>Text B</a>
    </h6>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) so that you can iterate to each matched elements:

```
$('div.copied-text').html(function(_,txt){
 //set the text for each .copied-text
  txt = $(this).parents('header') //find closest header
        .next() //next section element from header
        .find('a').text(); //find the link text
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed solution in one my projects that found nearest to mouse position element.

1) The nearest plugin was used - http://gilmoreorless.github.io/jquery-nearest/

2) The viewport plugin was used - http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

3) The call function is:

```
getNearestElementInView: function($element, eventData) {
        $element = $.nearest({
            x: eventData.pageX || 0,
            y: eventData.pageY || 0,
            sort: 'nearest',              

        }, $element.selector);

        return $element.filter(function() {
            return $.inviewport(this, { threshold: 0 });
        }).first();

    }
```

where `$element` is your selected elements and `eventData` is jquery event object.

You can call function like:

```
$(your_element_selector).on('mouseenter',function(ev){
getNearestElementInView($(this),ev);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Enjoy:)